# mysql: использование enum как параметры в хранимках

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, enum

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить такую проблему:

Есть таблица у которой одно из полей `field` имеет тип `enum`:

```
field enum('value1', 'value2')
```

и есть хранимая процедура `proc`, которая принимает на вход параметр, который будет записан в поле `field`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc`(
    IN field ENUM('value1', 'value2')
)
```

В какой-то момент я решил добавить в enum еще одно значение, чтобы было

```
field enum('value1', 'value2', 'value3')
```

И теперь мне придется, чтобы процедура корректно работала изменить еще и саму процедуру, дописав новое значение в поле параметров

Такой вопрос: а можно ли этого как-то избежать, просто указал как-нибудь, что входной параметр - это `enum`, но не перечисляя значения? Или как-то еще сформировать  входные параметры процедуры, чтоб изменив таблицу, не пришлось искать менять и значения везде

P.S.

понимаю, что вопрос наверное к плавильному проектированию БД и такие ситуации должны возникать не часто, но все же, как правильно поступать?

Comment: *как правильно поступать?* Не использовать ENUM. Использовать обычную схему со связанной таблицей-словарём.

Comment: @Akina, все так печально :(

Comment: @Akina, а чем плох enum?

Comment: @Qwertiy Так собственно проблема автора и вскрывает, чем он плох. Автору требуется синхронизировать определение в нескольких формально независимых точках кода. И это - исключительно ради автоматического преобразования индекса в значение? Допустимо для статического кода, но вряд ли разумно для развивающегося. Причём ENUM что хранится, что передаётся в виде SMALLINT UNSIGNED, и за преобразованием в текст ему надо сбегать в определение типа.. а какая разница, бегать туда или в таблицу-словарь? Плюс сортировка, которая плюёт на строковое представление и сортирует по индексу.

Comment: @Akina, ну у меня логика, что если существует специально созданный инструмент (в данном случае енум), то он должен работать как минимум не хуже, чем было бы без него (с таблицей).

Comment: @Qwertiy В определённых задачах он действительно работает лучше. Если список статический, а поле используется только локально, а не передаётся куда-то, как у автора, то ENUM вполне оправдывается.